# Web-SQL: Not creating more than 2 tables

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I'm not able to create more than 2 table in the database.

Code that I have tried:

```
    var db = openDatabase('myDB', '1.0', 'myDatabase',10*1024*1024);
    db.transaction(function (nw){
        nw.executeSql('Drop TABLE user');           
    });

    function db1(){
        var db = openDatabase('myDB', '1.0', 'myDatabase',10*1024*1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx){
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(empid varchar(10), name varchar(10), pass varchar(20), manager varchar(20)");
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO login (empid,name,pass,manager) VALUES ("1234567","Krishnaji","12345","9999999")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO login (empid,name,pass,manager) VALUES ("1000001","Gourav","12345","1234567")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO login (empid,name,pass,manager) VALUES ("1000002","Manju","12345","1234567")');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(empid varchar(10))');
            var x = $('#nameT').val();
            console.log(x);
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO user (empid) VALUES (?)', [x]);
            var u = $("#nameT").val();
            var p = $("#nameP").val();
            console.log(u);
            console.log(p);
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM login WHERE empid=? and pass=?',[u,p], function valid(){
                var len = results.rows.length;
                console.log(len);
                if (len == 1) {
                    window.location.assign("www/landing.html");
                } else{
                    alert("Invalid Employee ID or Password");
                };
            });
        });

        }
```

Is there any problem with the code?
None of the success function are being executed but the queries are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
function valid(tx,results){}
```

(tx,results) was missing.